# Swift using guard and fatal error specified in an function

Tags: ios, uitableview, enums, swift2

I use enum for building my `UITableView` cells:

```
  enum VAXSections: Int
  {
    case Segmented = 0
    case Scrollable = 1
    case ScheduledMode = 2
    case ScheduledFooter = 3
    case SilentHours = 4
    case SilentFooter = 5
  }
```

here how I use it:

```
  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
  {
    guard let unwrappedSection = VAXSections(rawValue: indexPath.section) else {
      showFatalError()
      return nil
    }
```

Few problem here I want to guard my section value if it's out of max case in my enum. For example if indexPath.section will be bigger then 5 then app should fall back. But if you see we can't return nil here, as `cellForRowAtIndexPath` has to return cell in any case.

I can solve problem by providing more readability with replacing showFatalError() fiction with:

```
    guard let unwrappedSection = VAXSections(rawValue: indexPath.section) else {
      fatalError("Check \(String(VAXUnitDashboardViewController.self)) UITableView datasource or check \(String(VAXSections.self)) enum.")
    }
```

then I don't need to return any value. But then I turned in another problem. As I need to specify at least 3 datasource functions of my `UITableView` I need to duplicate fatal error which I wish to replace with one function that do the same all the time:

`fatalError("Check \(String(VAXUnitDashboardViewController.self)) UITableView datasource or check \(String(VAXSections.self)) enum.")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
enum VAXItems: String {
    case Item1
    case Item2
    case Item3
}

enum VAXSections: String {
    case Segmented
    case Scrollable
    case ScheduledMode
    case ScheduledFooter
    case SilentHours
    case SilentFooter
}

struct VAXModel {
    var type: VAXSections
    var items: [VAXItems]
}
```

Then on your UIViewController you can have:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    private var model: [VAXModel] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        model = [
            VAXModel(type: .ScheduledMode, items: [.Item1, .Item2, .Item3]),
            VAXModel(type: .SilentFooter, items: [.Item1])
        ]

    }

    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return model.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return model[section].items.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(String(UITableViewCell), forIndexPath: indexPath)

        let item = model[indexPath.section].items[indexPath.row]

        switch item {
        case .Item1: cell.textLabel?.text = item.rawValue
        case .Item2: // Config
        case .Item3: // Config
        }

        return cell
    }

}
```

Comment: so in common is a really great solution, but in my case I have few switchers that should changes count of sections and count of rows. Also I have about 7 different type of UITableViewCells, that will be configured using switch in any case, so the problem I asked about is how to use guard in my case, because if you insert fatalError in body of guard you don't need to return value. I used some function that throw fatalError, but when you use custom function you need to return value in any case. So I get read of this using fatalError(fatalErrorDataSourceString())

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to have it in 3 places actually. Assuming that the 3 data source methods you are talking about are :

```
func numberOfSectionsInTableView(_ tableView: UITableView) -> Int
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
```

You actually need to have your guard in only one of them.

1. `numberOfSectionsInTableView` is the first method that will be called, so if you fail here, the other two methods won't be called. If the number of sections is based on some calculations, you can also cut off the value, something like this : `if calculatedNumberOfSections > 6 { return 6 } else { return calculatedNumberOfSections }` (remember that section numbering is `0` based)
2. `numberOfRowsInSection` - if you guard here you have two options - either fail with `fatalError` or (better in my opinion) - return `0` if a section number higher than `5` gets passed. Returning `0` will result in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` not being called with that section.
3. `cellForRowAtIndexPath` - you already got this :)

Comment: thanks for answer also I get rid of it by using this fatalError(fatalError(fatalErrorDataSource())) so I throw fatal error and just get the same string every time from one function.